# App not authenticating with React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am learning React-Native and trying to do oAuth2 authentication. I have registered my app with the service and my redirect uri. When the user clicks on the "login' button on the app, it is supposed to do the following:

```
onLoginPressed() {
        fetch("https://www.hackerschool.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=("+auth.client_id+")&redirect_uri=("+auth.redirect_uri+")")
          .then(response => _handleResponse(response))
          .catch(error => 
             this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              message: 'Something bad happened ' + error
           }));
        LinkingIOS.openURL("https://www.hackerschool.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=("+auth.client_id+")&redirect_uri=("+auth.redirect_uri+")");
    }
```

However, the response is the complete html render instead of the token that bounces me back to my redirect_uri which is my app.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you could extract the important code and create a gist or a small sample github project, then we could probably be in a better place to help.

Comment: @rahul2001 can you tell me how you got the redirect uri of your app as i am new not able to figure out that?

Comment: @user_4337270 did you ever figure it out? I am wondering the same thing here : ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244507/how-to-set-a-url-scheme-link-for-a-react-native-app

Comment: @httpNick nope if you have anything just forward it to me. :(

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is that Xcode is searching the library headers properly (especially with LinkingIOS).

"This step is not necessary for libraries that we ship with React Native with the exception of `PushNotificationIOS` and `LinkingIOS`."

[Linking React Native Libraries in Xcode](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries.html#step-3)

Answer (score 0):

Is the `LinkingIOS.openURL` function supposed to run after a response from the server in the `fetch` block? If so, then you'll want to include it in a another `then` block.

As it is written now, `LinkingIOS.openURL` will run right after the `fetch` line. Then, as they resolve or error out, the `then` and `catch` blocks of `fetch` will run.