# How to set a URL scheme/link for a react-native app

Tags: android, ios, oauth, react-native

I wanted to grant access to a react-native app using oauth for the spotify web api. I know I need to use [linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#content) to handle outgoing/incoming access to my app, but where can I specify the URI scheme of my react-native app so that the OS knows to go back to my app with the token?

Answer (score 3):

To specify the URL scheme, modify your AndroidManifest.xml and add an additional intent-filter under the one provided by react native. Update *yourscheme* & *yourhost* with your values.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="yourscheme"
            android:host="yourhost" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Comment: do I need to add android:host="" ? if yes then what should I add? thank you

Comment: Thank you, I looked for that all day.

Answer (score 0):

Linking is different for each platform. For a cross platform approach I recommend to look into: http://applinks.org

See this link for instructions how to set this up on iOS and Android: